# libc.so.6() (64-bit) is needed by .... ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, glibc

I am trying to install an odbc driver for vPostgres (Vmware's version for postgres) on Ubuntu 11.10 (64-bit).
I have downloaded the rpm file of the installer (64-bit) and when I try to install the rpm using:

rpm -ivh Vmware-vPostgres-client.rpm,   it shows me this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libresolv.so.2()(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libresolv.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
```

Few things I have tried:

locate libpthread.so.0 returns:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

/lib32/libpthread.so.0
```

I get similar locations for all other files:
locate libc.so.6

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

/lib32/libc.so.6
```

and so on.

I tried creating symlinks using:

```
sudo ln -s lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 /lib64/libc.so.6

sudo ln -s lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 /lib/libc.so.6

sudo ln -s lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 libc.so.6
```

but none of them worked. I am not sure where exactly it is trying to search for this files.

ldd Vmware-vPostgres-client.rpm doesnt help much and returns 
'not a dynamic executable' which is expected

I tried adding the path in the /etc/ld.so.conf file

include  lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

I also tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the specified file but of no use.

ldd --version shows
GLIBC 2.13

Can anyone help me out where exactly does it searches for the file?

Comment: Uhh, are you trying to install an rpm on Ubuntu??

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses the Debian packaging format, and so you cannot sensibly install RPMs on a Deb based distribution. While it is possible to install the `rpm` tool, the package dependencies don't integrate with those of Deb packages, and the contents of packages may not necessarily work either.

The best solution is to find a Deb package of the software you want, and the next best option is to build it into a Deb package yourself (which is a fair amount of work). If those are not possible, the last resort is to try using [alien](http://joeyh.name/code/alien/) to convert the RPM into a Deb. You will still need to deal with the dependencies manually, and possible with changes done in package scripts.

Answer (score 0):

"alien" works for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install alien
$ sudo alien VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64.rpm
vmware-vpostgres-client_1.0.1.1145-532312_amd64.deb generated
$ sudo dpkg -i vmware-vpostgres-client_1.0.1.1145-532312_amd64.deb
...
Unpacking vmware-vpostgres-client (from vmware-vpostgres-client_1.0.1.1145-532312_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up vmware-vpostgres-client (1.0.1.1145-532312) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```